# Resize overlay control with window resize

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a overlay control with a grid with few controls on it. On my WPF window I create an instance of this overlay as below

```
<overlays:OverlaySelector x:Name="Selector" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="3" Height="Auto"/>
```

My problem is that when I re-size my WPF window the overlay does not re-size. What could be the problem?

Comment: Any width or height values set on your Grid.Columns/Grid.Rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be manually resizing controls in WPF. Proper use of your control should do that for you. Try using the [`FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment(v=vs.110).aspx), [`FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.verticalalignment(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`FrameworkElement.Margin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin(v=vs.110).aspx) properties to automatically resize the control for you when the `Window` is resized. Try something like this:

```
<overlays:OverlaySelector x:Name="Selector" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
    Grid.Column="3" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="20" />
```

Of course, this won't work if you have hard coded any size or dimension values inside your `OverlaySelector` control.